# Cannot find 'ContentView' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I am trying to make a sign in page to my app using firebase but it says "Cannot find 'ContentView' in scope" and I don't know why

**Here is my RecipyApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main

struct RecipyApp: App{
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene{
        let viewModel = AppViewModel
        WindowGroup{
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
                
        }
        
    }
    
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate{
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        return true
        
    }
}
```

**Here is my ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth

class AppViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    @Published var signedIn = false
    
    var isSignedIn: Bool {
        
        return auth.currentUser != nil
    }
    
    
    func singIn(email: String, password: String){
        auth.signIn(withEmail: email,
                    password: password) { [weak self] result, error in
            guard result != nil, error == nil else{
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.signedIn = true
        }
        
    }
    
    func singUp(email: String, password: String){
        auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] result, error in
            guard result != nil, error == nil else{
                return
            
        }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.signedIn = true
        }
            
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            if viewModel.signedIn{
                Text("Signed In")
                
            }
            else{
                SignInView()
            }

    }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.signedIn = viewModel.isSignedIn
        }
    }
        
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
}


struct SignInView: View {
    
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
       
        VStack{
            TextField("Email Address", text: $email)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
            
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
            
            Button(action: {
                guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else{
                    return
                }
                viewModel.singIn(email: email, password: password)
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Sign In")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            })
        }
        .padding()
        Spacer()
            
    }
    }
        
}

struct SignUpView: View {
    
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
       
        VStack{
            TextField("Email Address", text: $email)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
            
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
            
            Button(action: {
                guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else{
                    return
                }
                $viewModel.singUp(email: email, password: password)
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Create Account")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            })
        }
        .padding()
        Spacer()
            
    }
    }
```

Why do I get this error because I have a ContentView struct?

Please any help would be appreciated as it has currently stopped development

Comment: Your `ContentView` and `ContentView_Previews` structs are within your `AppViewModel`.  Move them outside.

Comment: It helps us to help you when code is formatted correctly. As is, it appears ContentView is outside the AppViewModel, but as @rbaldwin suggested, it's actually inside that model which is throwing the error. Please take time to format your code for readability (and clarity!) when posting questions.

Comment: Moreover, try to separate each `View` or `Class` in its own file for readability , and clarity

Comment: Select your code and do CTRL+I to reformat, and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

in your RecipyApp you should have:

```
let viewModel = AppViewModel()  // <--- with the ()
```

and you are missing } for singIn and after singUp.

and you have one too many } after ContentView_Previews and SignInView

In other words check your brackets.