# Cannot find 'ContentView' in scope with UIKit and SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am trying to learn coding with swift using this video tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kecV6xPTTr8. I created my app folder, as I have called it, in Xcode as a newproject in iOS, writing ContentView.swift as follow

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIController{
    
    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .redcolor()
        return cv
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.frame = view.frame
    }
    
    
}
```

then when I run the app, I obtain this error *Cannot find 'ContentView' in scope*. The program app.swift has the following code

```
import SwiftUI


@main
struct app: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to correct the error as suggested here [Cannot find 'ContentView' in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234333/cannot-find-contentview-in-scope) and here, ["Cannot find 'ContentView' in scope in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70948896/cannot-find-contentview-in-scope-in-swift) and even to close Xcode or restart the computer, but they did not work. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Besides the issue you are reporting, note that there is no such class as `UIController` so there's no way that code will compile either.

Comment: You are kind-of mixing SwiftUI and UIKit, except your UIKit code isn't valid. I know people learn in different ways, but personally I don't understand using YouTube videos where you have to try and read code from a screen rather than web pages where you can just copy and paste. Also, that video is from 2016. It is likely to be very much out of date. Maybe try [Apple's tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Comment: These steps you have taken do not sound correct I suggest switching tutorials to either the [Apple provided](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training), [this](https://www.udemy.com/course/ios-13-app-development-bootcamp/) one on Udemy or "Hacking with Swift".

Comment: I also cannot find 'ContentView' in scope - can anyone else find it ?

Comment: I also tried to correct UIController to UIViewController as @HangarRash suggested but it give the same error. I don't understand again why because I have the same error using other temples. Please, any other idea?

Comment: UIKit is a framework to create iOS apps and SwiftUI is a newer framework to create iOS apps class ViewController  is written in UIKit and the struct app is written using SwiftUI you need some sort of a bridge to communicate  with each other. if you are trying to learn just swift  create something called [playground](https://designcode.io/swiftui-handbook-xcode-playground) but if you want to learn how to create apps just learn about UIKit and SwiftUI separately as other developers suggested in the comments